# DIY Visible light blocking filter (IR passing filter)

Tags: filters, diy, infrared

Which one is a better option (to block more visible light and to block less IR light), floppy disk or developed unexposed photographic film?

Comment: They're both terrible.  Film may be less terrible depending on... Color or B&W?  Negative or reversal?  Developed or undeveloped?

Comment: @xiota Which options are better for the film? I assume developed unexposed color film? am I correct? Thanks

Comment: There's info here that might be helpful: [Why isn't using exposed, undeveloped film working as a filter for my DIY infrared camera modification?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85958/75526)

Comment: @xiota If I understand correctly if it's negative film it has to be unexposed and it it's slide film it has to be exposed? Thanks

Comment: Yes, but... Why not just buy a cheap 720nm filter?  Results will be far superior.

Comment: @xiota The filters aren't particularly cheap where I live ... and I want this for headtracking for PC gaming, not for professional photography. Thank you very much for the information.

Comment: The developed color film option may be good enough then.  Good luck.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about photography (that is, making photographs with the end purpose of producing a photograph for artistic, historical, documentary, etc. usage), it is about using a camera as a measuring instrument.

Comment: @MichaelC While I want this for gaming it could still be useful for experimental artistic photography ...

Comment: @adudeeduda The application to experimental artistic photography has already been addressed here by questions such as [Why isn't using exposed, undeveloped film working as a filter for my DIY infrared camera modification?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85958/15871). In which case this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @MichaelC The answer about potential options and the exact way the positive/negative film should be prepared isn't clarified in that question, like it is in this one.

Comment: Also related: [What is the best choice of filter for infrared photography?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/13446/15871) and [What are the advantages of an 830nm infrared filter, in comparison to 720nm?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/84852/15871)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are lots of DIY IR-pass filters...

- Stacking colored gels (colored transparency sheets).
- Stacking ND filters.
- Crossing polarizing filters.
- Variable ND filter.
- Floppy disk – particularly poor because of metal content.
- Developed color film.  Unexposed if reversal (slide film).  Exposed if negative. – Undeveloped and B&W films won't work well because of metal content.

None of them is as good as cheap IR-pass filters.  They come in different frequencies that have slightly different effects.  720nm is the most commonly recommended.

If you are shooting digital, modify your camera for "full spectrum" capture.  There are inexpensive premodified compact cameras available for sale online.

See also:

[Why isn't using exposed, undeveloped film working as a filter for my DIY infrared camera modification?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/85958/75526)